# SQL Equivalent of Countif or Index Match on row level instead of columnar level

Tags: sql-server, excel-formula, count, countif

I have a table which comprises of 30 columns, all adjacent to one another. Of these 5 are text fields indicating certain details pertaining to that entry and 25 are value fields. Value fields have the column name as Val00, Val01, Val02 .....upto Val24

Based on a logic appearing elsewhere, these value fields input a value for n amount of columns and then drop to 0 for all of the subsequent fields

e.g.
When n is 5 the output will be

| Val00 | Val01 | Val02 | Val03 | Val04 | Val05 | Val06 | Val07 | Val24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

As can be seen, all values starting from val05 will drop to 0 and all columns from Val 05 to Val24 will be 0.

Given this output, I want to find what this n value is and create a new column `ValCount` to store this value in it.

In Excel this would be fairly straight forward to achieve with the below formula

```
=COUNTIF(Val00:Val24,">0")
```

However I'm not sure how we would go about in terms of SQL. I understand that the count function works on a columnar level and not on a row level.

Comment: I would posit that your table is denormalized: you shouldn't have 25 separate columns to store similar data. Store it in 25 separate rows, then you can do a simple `COUNT`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is rather long but it should do the job so I hope it helps you.

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN Val00 >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     + SUM(CASE WHEN Val01 >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + SUM(CASE WHEN Val02 >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) As ValCount
```

Comment: Thanks @BrianOrion
Currently I'm using a similar approach by using CASE WHEN syntax. However as you said it's quite a bit long. Hence I wanted to check if any shorter solution existed, wherein From: and To: columns could be mentioned along with the condition to extract the count.
Additionally I also have a database which has 100+columns sequentially next to each other, wherein I need to create a similar column.

Comment: @x0nar so now you can see why you need to show us your attempt, to avoid people wasting their time with something you have already tried!